# Wicket: Is it possible to display components of a panel based on page the panel is added to?

Tags: templates, wicket, panel, wicket-1.5, webpage-rendering

I'm pretty new to Wicket, so please excuse me if this is a simple task. I tried to look for examples but came up empty.

Here's the scenario. Lets say that I have a customer information panel with 25 data points (name, dob, address, phone, etc). I want to reuse this panel in many different pages on a site. Now lets say I have the following criteria on 3 different pages the panel appears on:

- Page 1 - All fields are visible and editable
- Page 2 - Date of Birth, Gender, Customer Name are visible but not
  editable, all other fields are visible and editable
- Page 3 - Date of Birth and Gender are not visible, Address is visible
  and editable, all other fields are visible but not editable.

Is there a way to use the same panel (to reduce code duplication), but control its components based on the current page the panel is loaded into?

Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would suggest against changing the visibility and editability implicitly like this. Instead consider making it explicit based on constructor arguments for the component or additional methods on the custom component.

Comment: Yes, I was hoping for a solution that might allow passing in a list of the fields to hide and a list of fields to make non-editable. Just wasn't sure if wicket supported that type of behavior. From your and artbristol's answers it seems that it may.

Comment: The easiest way is to declare an enum in your panel class with 3 values: FULL_EDIT, PARTIAL_EDIT, HIDDEN_EDIT (or something along those lines) describing the available operating modes, and make your page pass an instance of it to the panel. Remember, the less the pages know about the internals of the panel, the better.

Comment: The problem I see with adding an enum is that then the panel will have to know every unique configuration and implement complicated if/then or switch statements that would have to be maintained as new pages (with new configuration requirements) are added.

Answer (score 1):

Inside your panel you can call the `getPage()` method. Either you can check if the page is instance of a certain class our you can get the page class by calling `getPageClass()`.

The visibility of your components inside the panel can be set by calling the `setVisible()` method or by overriding the `isVisible()` method. If components should be editable can be controlled by using the `isEnabled()` method (or overriding `setEnabled()`).

```
class YourPanel extends Panel {
    public YourPanel() {
        add(new TextField("name") {
                @Override
                boolean isVisible() {
                    return getPage().getPageClass().equals(Page2.class);
                }
        }
        TextField genderTextField = new TextField("gender");
        genderTextField.setVisible(!getPage().getPageClass().equals(Page3.class));
        add(genderTextField);
    }
}
```

As you can see, for many components and many cases to check the code will be quite complex. Maybe you can get cleaner code if you create custom panels, add the components according to their visibility and editability rules and control for the whole panels if they are visible and/or editable.

Comment: I was trying to avoid hard coding attributes in the panel based on specific pages. Was hoping for a more flexible solution. I was also hoping to avoid having to duplicate the info on several different custom panels since it's really all the same information over and over again.

Answer (score 0):

Per the other answer, you can call `setVisible()` and the like to customize the appearance.

I don't recommend you couple your panel to the displaying page, however; this will introduce circular dependency, and each time you want to reuse the panel on a new type of page, you'd have to add in another check for the new page. Instead, just make the panel configurable (best to do this at construction time by passing parameters such as `boolean addressVisible`).

Comment: Exactly, I was trying to avoid all coupling from the panel to the page. Definitely wanted to go the parameter route. I'll play around with that and see how it works out.