# Wicket: Go to the page with an activated panel

Tags: wicket, panel

I am developing a web application with wicket 1.5. Now i have a problem.
The target page which should be redirected to includes four different panels(Panel 1,2,3,4). How to get a page instance which has an activated panel 3? Normally the new XXXPage() method will return an page instance with an activated panel 1.

Regards
lancel

Answer (score 0):

Use PageParameters to indicate which panel should be active.  This is very similar to the [question asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11193088/wicket-is-it-possible-to-display-components-of-a-panel-based-on-page-the-panel)